# Updating a page every time I revisit the page in BottomNavigationbar

Tags: flutter, datastore, sqflite, flutter-bottomnavigation

In my app the user is able to store favorite items on a different page in the bottom navigation bar. My problem is that the page does not refresh properly. If you add a favorite it gets displayed only when restarting the app.
If the favorites page is in the same widget hierarchy of the respective bottomnavitem the function works fine.

https://pastebin.com/nZ2jrLqK

```
    class Favorites extends StatefulWidget {
  const Favorites({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FavoritesState createState() => _FavoritesState();
}

class _FavoritesState extends State<Favorites> {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var database;
  List<Mechanism> people = <Mechanism>[];

  Future initDb() async {
    database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'person_database.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        return db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE person(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  name TEXT, height TEXT, mass TEXT, hair_color TEXT, skin_color TEXT, eye_color TEXT, birth_year TEXT, gender TEXT)",
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );

    getPeople().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        people = value;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<List<Mechanism>> getPeople() async {
    final Database db = await database;

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('person');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return Mechanism(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        name: maps[i]['name'] as String,
      );
    });
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDb();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backGround,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: appbarColor,
        title: const Text("Favorites"),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: people.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var person = people[index];
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(
                person.name,
                style: const TextStyle(color: titleColor),
              ),
              onTap: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) =>
                          MechanismDtl(mechanism: person, id: index)),
                );
              },
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Edit: page where the user can store the items

```
class MarkFavs extends StatefulWidget {
  const MarkFavs({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MarkFavsState createState() => _MarkFavsState();
}

class _MarkFavsState extends State<MarkFavs> {
  TextEditingController searchController = TextEditingController();
  List<People> shownList = <People>[
    People(name: 'Test', id: 1),
    People(name: 'Test2', id: 2),
    People(name: 'Test3', id: 3)
  ];
  List<People> initialData = <People>[
    People(name: 'Test', id: 1),
    People(name: 'Test2', id: 2),
    People(name: 'Test3', id: 3)
  ];

  void queryPeople(String queryString) {
    if (kDebugMode) {
      print("queryString = $queryString");
    }

    setState(() {
      shownList = initialData.where((string) {
        if (string.name.toLowerCase().contains(queryString.toLowerCase())) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }).toList();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backGround,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: appbarColor,
        title: const Text('Detail'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextButton.icon(
            label: const Text('Favorites'),
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.storage,
              color: titleColor,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const Favorites()),
              );
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: PeopleList(
              people: shownList,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PeopleList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<People> people;

  const PeopleList({Key key, this.people}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: people.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var person = people[index];
        var name = person.name;
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(
            name,
            style: const TextStyle(color: titleColor),
          ),
          onTap: () {
            person.id = index;
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) =>
                      MechanismDtl(mechanism: person, id: index)),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the most efficient method, but if you provide a passback to the Favourites class from the parent widget you can call a setState in the parent widget (assuming the parent widget reloads the database).

```
    class Favorites extends StatefulWidget {
  const Favorites({Key? key, this.passback}) : super(key: key);
  final Function passback;

  @override
  _FavoritesState createState() => _FavoritesState();
}
```

Then the passback would look like:

```
passback() {
   setState(){
     //Reload db
   }
}
```

And pass it into Favourite (does not work with named routes AFAIK)

```
  Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Favourites(passback: passback)),
 );
```

Then just call passback when the user adds the item to their favourites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Do I insert the passback function in the Favorite class or in its parent widget?

Comment: You create the function in the parent widget and pass it to the favourite class.

Comment: Somehow I cannot implement your solution. I added the page where the user can mark the items as favorites. Would be grateful if you could glance through it

Comment: create a pastebin / github repo (anywhere you can upload it) with your code and i'll be happy to look over it :) @Nick

Comment: Here is the pastebin repo: https://pastebin.com/nZ2jrLqK. Let me know if you need any further code. Thank you so much!

Comment: I haven't had a chance to debug, but from a first glance, having the tabBuilder return the TabViews means you can't use my suggested fix as the two widgets are decoupled and not parent/child. Only thing I could suggest is maybe calling a method to refresh the data from the database within the Widget build {} of the page that holds the list of favourites, that way when you return to it and it rebuilds in theory it should get the favourites that were added. Likely inefficient as it would do it on every rebuild, but its a start.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it quite ugly but it is working. If you know a better way please let me know!

```
class Favorites extends StatefulWidget {
  const Favorites({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _FavoritesState createState() => _FavoritesState();
}

class _FavoritesState extends State<Favorites> {
  // ignore: prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables
  var database;
  List<TestItems> items = <TestItems>[];

  Future initDb() async {
    database = await openDatabase(
      join(await getDatabasesPath(), 'person_database.db'),
      onCreate: (db, version) {
        db.execute(
          "CREATE TABLE person(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,  name TEXT)",
        );
      },
      version: 1,
    );

    getItems().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        items = value;
      });
    });
  }

  Future<List<TestItems>> getItems() async {
    final Database db = await database;

    final List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db.query('person');
    return List.generate(maps.length, (i) {
      return TestItems(
        id: maps[i]['id'],
        name: maps[i]['name'] as String,
      );
    });
  }

  Future<void> deleteDB(int id) async {
    final db = await database;
    await db.delete(
      'person',
      where: "id = ?",
      whereArgs: [id],
    );
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDb();
  }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
// Updates the page every time the build method gets called
        initDb().then((value) {
          setState(() {
            items = value;
          });
        });
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: const Text("Favorites"),
            ),
            body: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: items.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  var item = items[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      item.name,
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ItemDtl(items: item, id: index)),
                      );
                    },
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.delete_forever_rounded),
                      onPressed: () {
                        deleteDB(item.id).then((value) {
                          getItems().then((value) {
                            setState(() {
                              items = value;
                            });
                          });
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide some more explanation on what does your code do?